# How look up Azure Event Initiated By ID

Tags: azure

I am trying to understand who has created a VM in Azure subscription. In the Activity Log of the VM i see the EVENT INITIATED BY equal to

8xxxxxx1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

It does not correspond to any Users' objectID. How can i look up that ID to find out the user behind?

thanks

Comment: You should see OPERATION NAME `Create or Update Virtual Machine` and 
EVENT INITIATED BY someID in the activity log, the someID is who created this VM.

Comment: Right this is what i mentioned. However that someID does not correspond to any user (objectID) i can see in the Portal. So i was wondering if i could use an API to look up the subject.

Comment: Check if it is the object id of your service principal, use this powershell command: `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId 8xxxxxx1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Could you get it? If you did not use azure ad powershell, just run the command in the azure cloud shell in the portal, see this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart-powershell

Comment: @JoyWang thanks. I got it, something like AppId and DisplayName = AzureContainerService Does it mean the VM was created as part of this cluster?

Comment: It means the vm was created via the service principal named `AzureContainerService`.

Comment: Not familiar with container service, maybe what you said is correct.

Comment: can anybody with permission used the SP AzureContainerService or is it reserved (implicitly) to Azure? I have this issue and trying to find out the root cause why our routetable was delete (under public IP delete)

Comment: found it, it's in the activity logs of AKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM was created by a service principal, just try the command as below to get it.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId 8xxxxxx1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```